# php and ffmpeg: how to set parameter '-c:v' 'copy' in php?

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg-php

I am using phpffmpeg library with Laravel

```
 $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::fromDisk($disk)
          ->open($videoPathDisk)
            ->getFrameFromSeconds(1)
            ->export()
          ->toDisk($disk);

          $ffmpeg->save($path.$videoPoster);
```

The process is very slow. When I use command like ffmpeg with  '-c:v' 'copy' parameters, process speeds up.

Question: How can I inject that parameter to my phpffmpeg snippet ?

Comment: I think you're looking for custom filters. Docs available here https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg#custom-filters

Comment: ``FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')->open('steve_howe.mp4')->addFilter('-c', 'v')....`` something like this should work